# Inconsistent EventBridge Rule Execution In AWS: Seeking Guidance For Ensuring Proper Intervals In API Calls"

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, events

I've configured an `EventBridge` rule in AWS to trigger an API call every 3 hours, and I've implemented logging to monitor these calls in CloudWatch. However, I've noticed inconsistent behavior in the intervals, with occurrences at 2 hours, 4 hours, or even multiple times within a minute. Could you provide insights into why this variability is happening, and how I can ensure a consistent 3-hour interval between API calls?

Despite creating multiple `EventBridge` rules to trigger a specific API call every 3 hours, the execution remains inconsistent. The expectation is that the API call should occur precisely after 3 hours, yet the observed behavior includes variations in intervals, such as calls at 2 hours, 4 hours, or even multiple times within a minute. Seeking assistance to troubleshoot and achieve a stable 3-hour interval for the API calls.